# Is it possible to get TLS client auth cert info from jax-rs?

Tags: java, jax-rs, client-certificates

I am in an OSGi environment. I use jax-rs class for RESTServiceRegistration. I have configured the layers underneath to require client certification auth during the TLS handshake. Now I would like to access it from my service.

This is a pseudo code how I tried to access the X509 subject CommonName.

Interface (this is used for the REST webservice registration):

```
@GET
@WebMethod
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/tls")
public String soutTLSClientCertInfo(@Context SomeContext context);
```

This is the implementation:

```
@Override
public String soutTLSClientCertInfo(@Context SomeContext context) {
    return context.getAttribute("java.etwas....tsl.cn_name");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found an answer...
HttpServletRequest is autoinjected if you have something like this

```
private HttpServletRequest request;

@Context public void setHttpServletRequest( HttpServletRequest request ) {
    this.request = request;
}
```

Later you can use it like:

```
@Override
public String getTlsInfo() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(  );
    X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
    for (X509Certificate cert: certs) {
        stringBuilder.append(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
    }
    return stringBuilder;
}
```

You should also be careful with the javax.servlet version...